# JQuery get non stand html tags

Tags: jquery, openlayers

Is this possible?

http://jsfiddle.net/bQLPt/4/

```
if ($('svg image[href="Images/pin_icon_red_unit.png"]').length {

alert("red");     

 }



<svg id="OpenLayers.Layer.Vector_179_svgRoot" width="1556" height="556" viewBox="0 0 1556 556"><g id="OpenLayers.Layer.Vector_179_root" style="display: block; visibility: visible; " transform=""><g id="OpenLayers.Layer.Vector_179_vroot"><image id="OpenLayers.Geometry.Point_238" cx="778" cy="278" r="1" preserveAspectRatio="none" x="758" y="258" width="40" height="40" href="Images/pin_icon_red_unit.png" style="opacity: 1" fill="#000000" fill-opacity="1" stroke="#000000" stroke-opacity="1" stroke-width="1" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-dasharray="none" pointer-events="visiblePainted"></image><image id="OpenLayers.Geometry.Point_240" cx="906" cy="406" r="1" preserveAspectRatio="none" x="886" y="386" width="40" height="40" href="Images/pin_icon_red_unit.png" style="opacity: 1" fill="#000000" fill-opacity="1" stroke="#000000" stroke-opacity="1" stroke-width="1" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-dasharray="none" pointer-events="visiblePainted"></image><image id="OpenLayers.Geometry.Point_242" cx="1034" cy="534" r="1" preserveAspectRatio="none" x="1014" y="514" width="40" height="40" href="Images/pin_icon_red_unit.png" style="opacity: 1" fill="#000000" fill-opacity="1" stroke="#000000" stroke-opacity="1" stroke-width="1" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-dasharray="none" pointer-events="visiblePainted"></image></g><g id="OpenLayers.Layer.Vector_179_troot"></g></g></svg>​
```

Comment: Can you be a little more clear as to what you want to do, and clean up your code so it at least doesn't have syntax errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

Your example code didn't work as you missed a closing parenthesis.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Q3DZA/).

Answer (score 2):

You're missing a parenthesis.

http://jsfiddle.net/bQLPt/5/

```
if ($('svg image[href="Images/pin_icon_red_unit.png"]').length) {
```

Answer (score 2):

You didnt close your if statement

http://jsfiddle.net/6RNQZ/